# SelectAll() Not working after adding text boxes to a group box

Tags: .net, vb.net, basic

I was able to have my program select all text inside of a text box when the user clicks the box.

```
 Private Sub txtPreserve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txtPreserve.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

I am required (homework) to put the text boxes inside of a groupbox in order to use a for each loop on them. After putting them inside a groupbox, the selectAll() function no longer works. It was working wonderfully.

I imagine I need to specify the text box in a different way before issuing the .selectAll() function. IF anyone knows a work around or an alternative method, I would greatly appreciate it.

edit: to be clear, the program still compiles and runs fine. It simply does not select the text to make it easier for the user to replace the text.

Comment: How did you move them into the GroupBox?  If cut-paste, you severed the event, in which case you have to subscribe to it again.

Comment: I did cut and paste, a quick google search brought me to that conclusion.

Comment: In the future, try to drag the controls into a new container.  That will preserve the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the click event:

```
Private Sub txtPreserve_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPreserve.Click
    txtPreserve.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

Sometimes when cut and pasting controls you can lose the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have multiple textboxes where you might want the same behavior.  In that case the following might be an efficient solution:

```
Private Sub MyMultipleEventHandler (ByVal sender as System.Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles txtPreserve.Click, txt2.Click, txt3.Click
    Dim tb as textbox = sender
    sender.SelectAll()
End Sub
```

This will map all of the textbox click events to the same handler.  **sender** represents the object that sent the event, in this case, the indiviudal textbox.
Casting **sender** as a Textbox lets you invoke SelectAll() on that textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue lately. My solution was to set the textbox as the active control before calling textbox.SelectAll()

```
 ActiveControl = textbox
 textbox.SelectAll()
```